# Why Norton Ghost 2003 won't work on a Eee PC Netbook 1101-HAB?

Tags: boot, netbook, norton-ghost

The PC has 1GB RAM, 160GB HDD, and Windows XP Home. The Norton Ghost included PC-DOS crashes/restarts during boot-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because PC-DOS does not recognize the controller.

all, however, is not lost: you can, use **ghost32.exe** (which you can extract from the ASUS system DVD, IIRC it is inside a disk image called WinPE.iso) with **[BartPE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/)**, works like a charm.

and since your eee PC doesn't have a DVD drive, you might as well transfer your BartPE image to a USB stick, **[WinToFlash](http://wintoflash.com/home/en/)** makes it a breeze.

*Bart's PE builder and WinToFlash are freeware.*

note: you need **ghost32.exe**, ghost.exe will not work in BartPE (or any Win32 environment for that matter.)